# Random X-Server fails when booting (Maybe driver Issue)

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, recovery-mode, proprietary

So I have this Problem for quite some time now but I dont even know what to google. Sometimes when I boot Ubuntu the sceen will show some bootup messages and then turn black. This doesn't happen everytime and to this day I dont know if it is reproducable or purely random. SSH works, but things like restarting lightdm or killing X-related processes wont change a thing.

So I push the power button on my Desktop or shut it down via ssh. The pc wont shut down completely in both cases. The screen shows some messages about busy mounts but the HDD has spun down so I forcefully power it off.

My "Workaround" at the moment to get my ubuntu to start is booting recovery mode, then selecting failsafeX. After that, I will get the Error-message telling me my graphics ar not working properly. I then switch console to tty1 (because I cant click on the Button in the error-message) and just hit Ctrl-C. this will then finally start Ubuntu the way it should. I dont know why this works I just found it working.

Shutting down then works like its supposed to (or at least like it does after a normal boot. It still takes too long in my opinion).

I use the proprietary driver for my GTX 970 and because I sometimes mess around with CUDA stuff its kind of necessary.

Ubuntu is Installed on A SSD next to a Windows 8 Install. Fast boot is disabled under Windows and I installed both OSes in BIOS-Mode. I really hope someone could help me out because I use this PC almost everyday and it botheres me a lot.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue. I fixed it by reinstalling drivers and Xserver and by also deleting Xauthoriy file:

1.
Boot computer and ctrl alt 1-7 into tty and log in.
Run:

```
Sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*

Sudo reboot
```

2. On reboot, open grub menu by holding shift during boot. Edit the grub and add 'nomodeset' to the end of the Linux line (after 'quiet splash'). Then hit F10 to boot.
   3.
   Open tty like before

   Sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

   Sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

   Sudo rm ~/.Xauthoriy

   Sudo reboot
3. Boot as normal. No need to edit grub.
4. Your issue should be resolved

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I will do that immediately and hope for the best